# about reading file using loop, process and writing something to a new line in another file using Python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm writing a Python program which takes the Twitter name from one txt.file that contains a list of Twitter names, get the number of followers from the Twitter API and then write it to another txt.file. (every follower_count takes one line in the file I'm writing to.)

My program is now as follows, which contains some bugs and could anyone help me debug it. It's not running.

My program:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
CONSUMER_KEY = 'abc'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'abc'
ACCESS_KEY = 'abc'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'abc'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
f = open('Twitternames.txt', 'r')
for x in f:
    class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
#search
api = tweepy.API(auth)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())
test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=['x'])
for user in test:
    print user.followers_count 
    #print it out and also write it into a file

    f = open('followers_number.txt', 'w')
    string = user.followers_count
    f.write(string/n)

f.close()
```

I am getting the following  error:

`File "twittercount.py", line 21 def on_data(self, data): ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: Please define `It's not running.` What is the expected output versus the observed output? Do you have errors? What is your actual question?

Comment: the terminal shows:   File "twittercount.py", line 21
    def on_data(self, data):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
tiffdeMacBook-Air:~ tiff$ python twittercount.py
  File "twittercount.py", line 21
    def on_data(self, data):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block @Celeo Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you `f = open('followers_number.txt', 'w')` you overwrite the contents, open the file outside the loop and use `a` to append if you want to keep the data from previous run.

```
with  open('followers_number.txt', 'a') as f: # with close your files automatically
    for user in test:
        print user.followers_count 
        #print it out and also write it into a file
        s = user.followers_count
        f.write(s +"\n") # add a newline with +
```

If `user.followers_count` returns an int you will need to use `str(s)`

You need to declare your class first not inside a loop and the methods should be inside the class:

```
# create class first
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data): # indented inside the class
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

# open both files outside the loop
with open('Twitternames.txt') as f,open('followers_number.txt', 'a') as f1:
    for x in f:   
        #search
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())
        test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=[x]) # pass the variable not "x" 
        for user in test:
            print(user.followers_count)
            #print it out and also write it into a file
            s = user.followers_count
            f1.write("{}\n".format(s)) # add a newline with +
```

Comment: File "twittercount.py", line 21
    def on_data(self, data):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block    thank you for your help! and my terminal shows the above information. (line 21 is: def on_data(self, data):        Could you help identify what's the problem with my program? this is my first time using Python and also StackOverflow, and thank you so much!!

Comment: @TiffGong,  I updated your code, indentation is critical in python, you also need to declare your class first not in the loop. Also for your own sake adding any errors to your question will help your cause.

Comment: Hi! That was very nice of you!! and I've changed my program to your modified version, which is much better now! But still two problems: 1) When I run it, the terminal keeps tying "23851" in new rows, which is the number of followers of the first Twitter name in my file f; I believe this means that the pointer was not moving in file f, but I'm not sure how this should be done properly in Python   2) when I check my file f1, there's nothing, i.e. the program is not writing to f1 as expected. Could you help me further with this? Thank you so much for you time and patience!!@Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @TiffGong, when you `print x` in the first for loop what do you see?

Comment: I see 23851 and another 23851 in the next line and another ....so I think the loop works, but the pointer of the file f was not moving, and f1 was not written with 23851 as well@Padraic Cunningham

Comment: add a couple of lines from your file so we can make sure there is what you think in there :) , the pointer is definitely moving.

Comment: I see what was happening, you were passing the string  ' x' to `screen_names=` when it should just be `x` the variable

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "try.py", line 32, in <module>
    test = api.lookup_users(screen_names=x)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 321, in lookup_users   return self._lookup_users(post_data=post_data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 239, in _call  return method.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute  raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Headers indicate a formencoded body but body was not decodable.

Comment: oh you're so nice.. but after changing the x, the terminal shows the above when I try to run the program.. I have no idea what it's talking about, and I want to attach my program to this place but it seems to be too long , are there any way I can do this? @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: You can add the relevant data here http://pastebin.com/, just create a new paste and copy the url

Comment: I tested the code myself and it works well,  there must be something strange happening in your file.